# Spring Boot Security, как настроить русский логин?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

В **pom.xml** добавляем:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

В application.properties прописываем:

```
spring.security.user.name=Маша
spring.security.user.password=masha
```

Пытаемся логиниться, получаем "Неверные учетные данные пользователя".
Как починить?

И попутно: есть ли простой способ сделать стандартную страничку логина по-русски? "Неверные учетные данные пользователя" он пишет по-русски, а "Please sign in" по-английски :) Хочется однообразия что ли :)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему переводом конфига с `application.properties` на `application.yml`.

Так кодировка *человечья*.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).